# Groovy closure does not modify a value in delegated object

Tags: object, groovy, closures

The Groovy code shown below contains closures and a method. That format changed label and expected to receive that change label shows the problem and the requirement.

```
def method (String a, Closure c) {
    Query q = new Query()
    q.a = a
    c.delegate = q
    c.call()
    def str = q.str
}
class Query
{
    def str
    def a
    void key (String str, Closure cls) {
        this.str = str
        Pass p = new Pass()
        p.a=a
        cls.delegate=p
        cls.call()
        def val=p.a      // Expcted to receive that change
        println val

    } 
    class Pass
    {
        String a
    } 
}

method("got") {
    key ("got"){
        a=a.toUpperCase() // Format Changed here
        println a

    }
}
```

Actual Output is :

```
GOT
got
```

But my expected output is:

```
GOT
GOT
```

Why that `a = a.toUpperCase()` doesn't change a value in `p` object after the `cls.call()`? How to pass this change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change delegate resolving strategy for `cls` in `key(String str, Closure cls)` method to:

```
cls.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
```

Default strategy is `Closure.OWNER_FIRST`. In case of a Groovy script it means that [the owner of this closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#closure-owner) is an instance of a class that was generated by Groovy to run the script. In case of your Groovy script this class looks like this:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Closure;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GeneratedClosure;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class my_groovy_script extends Script {
    public my_groovy_script() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    }

    public my_groovy_script(Binding context) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        var1[0].call(InvokerHelper.class, my_groovy_script.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        class _run_closure1 extends Closure implements GeneratedClosure {
            public _run_closure1(Object _thisObject) {
                CallSite[] var3 = $getCallSiteArray();
                super(my_groovy_script.this, _thisObject);
            }

            public Object doCall(Object it) {
                CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
                class _closure2 extends Closure implements GeneratedClosure {
                    public _closure2(Object _thisObject) {
                        CallSite[] var3 = $getCallSiteArray();
                        super(_run_closure1.this, _thisObject);
                    }

                    public Object doCall(Object it) {
                        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
                        Object var3 = var2[0].call(var2[1].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this));
                        ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(var3, _closure2.class, this, (String)"a");
                        return var2[2].callCurrent(this, var2[3].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(this));
                    }

                    public Object doCall() {
                        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
                        return this.doCall((Object)null);
                    }
                }

                return var2[0].callCurrent(this, "got", new _closure2(this.getThisObject()));
            }

            public Object doCall() {
                CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
                return this.doCall((Object)null);
            }
        }

        return var1[1].callCurrent(this, "got", new _run_closure1(this));
    }

    public Object method(String a, Closure c) {
        CallSite[] var3 = $getCallSiteArray();
        Query q = (Query)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var3[2].callConstructor(Query.class), Query.class);
        ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(a, my_groovy_script.class, q, (String)"a");
        ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty(q, my_groovy_script.class, c, (String)"delegate");
        var3[3].call(c);
        Object str = var3[4].callGroovyObjectGetProperty(q);
        return str;
    }
}
```

As you can see every Groovy script is actually a class that extends `groovy.lang.Script` class. There is one important thing about this class - it overrides:

- [`public Object getProperty(String property)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L54)
- [`public void setProperty(String property, Object newValue)`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/groovy/lang/Script.java#L62)

If you take a look at the source code of both methods you will see that it uses `binding` object to store and access all variables in scope of the closure. That's why the closure you pass to `Query.key(String str, Closure cls)` does not modify a `a` field of class `Pass` but instead it creates a local binding `a` with a value `GOT`. You can change this behavior by changing Closure's resolve strategy to `Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST`. This will do the trick because you explicitly set `cls.delegate` to `p` instance so the closure will firstly look for a field `a` in `p` instance. I hope it helps.

#### Updated Groovy script

```
def method(String a, Closure c) {
    Query q = new Query()
    q.a = a
    c.delegate = q
    c.call()
    def str = q.str
}

class Query {
    def str
    def a

    void key(String str, Closure cls) {
        this.str = str
        Pass p = new Pass()
        p.a = a
        cls.delegate = p
        cls.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        cls.call()
        def val = p.a      // Expcted to receive that change
        println val

    }

    class Pass {
        String a
    }
}

method("got") {
    key("got") {
        a = a.toUpperCase() // Format Changed here
        println a

    }
```

#### Output

```
GOT
GOT
```